# SQL Join tables with variable column

Tags: sql, join

I'm wanting to join for comparison two separate systems tons calculations for each Table1.BOXID

Table 1 has already summarized Tons for each BOXID. I need to SUM all the Tons from Table2.Tons that have a Datetime between Table1 starttime & endtime and join it to Table1 with a new column UnitTons

Table 1

| BOXID | TONS | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P8855 | 2541 | 2024-03-16 10:48:08.990 | 2024-03-17 08:30:00.000 |
| P5874 | 4526 | 2024-03-13 14:40:00.000 | 2024-03-14 15:00:00.000 |

Table 2

| Unit | DATEIME | TONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F56 | 2024-03-16 10:56:08.990 | 846 |
| F85 | 2024-03-16 11:48:08.990 | 839 |
| F85 | 2024-03-17 05:48:08.990 | 850 |
| F55 | 2024-03-13 14:13:08.990 | 1128 |
| F89 | 2024-03-13 14:28:08.990 | 1215 |
| F35 | 2024-03-13 14:33:08.990 | 988 |
| F75 | 2024-03-13 14:42:08.990 | 1187 |

Output table

| BOXID | TONS | STARTTIME | ENDTIME | UnitTons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P8855 | 2541 | 2024-03-16 10:48:08.990 | 2024-03-17 08:30:00.000 | 2535 |
| P5874 | 4526 | 2024-03-13 14:40:00.000 | 2024-03-14 15:00:00.000 | 4518 |

I assume I'll need a while clause for each row of table1 with a sub routine summing Table2.Tons with a while clause of datetime between Table1.STARTTIME and Table1.ENDTIME but I'm really battling with syntax

Comment: I think you mean `where` clause, not `while`. General idea would be something like `select table1.boxid, table1.tons, table1.starttime, table1.endtime, sum(table2.TONS) as UnitTons from Table1 join table2 on (table1.starttime <= table2.datetime and table1.endtime >= table2.datetime) group by boxid, tons, starttime, endtime`.

Comment: What database are you using, please?

Comment: Can we see a schema for table1? Is boxid the primary key?

Comment: Your results do not add up. F55, F89, and F35 are not inside any time range.

Answer (score 0):

First, join table2 with table1 on datetime being between starttime and endtime. I've used a `left join` so all rows of table1 are output, even if they have no matching rows in table2. See [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Then `group by boxid` and sum table2.tons. I've assumed that boxid is the primary key. If not you'll have to `group by boxid, tons, starttime, endtime`; this will work, but it indicates a problem with your table design.

```
select t1.*, sum(t2.tons) as unittons
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.datetime between t1.starttime and t1.endtime
group by boxid
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/AHUt8V8g).

Note: the results differ from yours because F55, F89, and F35 are not inside any table1 time range.

Note: PostgreSQL has [`tsrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), a range type for timestamps. Using a single column `tsrange` has many advantages; [there are many range functions you can take advantage of](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) and [more efficient indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING).

Comment: So I ended up using this for my solution, apologies my explanation and example weren't very good with errors. I had to add a couple CASE when in my select statement because the problem was more complex than I described, however you simple solution pointed me in the right direction. Thank you